# Is there any advice for deciding which law firm should I go with a case about losing money in stock investments

Tags: lawyer

I lost a lot of money investing a listed company which might have violated the law. However, after searching on Google/Twitter I noticed that there are many law firms able to provide law help to me, for free.

I have finally got in touch with two law firms and they both told me that I can only work with one of them. It sounds fair enough and I'm okay with that. They both give me one month to make the final decision.

How could I make the best decision for myself? Is there any public data like how successful a law firm is? Since I've lost a lot of money, I hope to make a perfect decision at my best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I look for when seeking a lawyer?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/what-should-i-look-for-when-seeking-a-lawyer)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what the law firms told you is incorrect. People have multiple lawyers all the time. The lawyers just don't want to share the money, which means they probably think there is not a lot of it. If you had a strong $20 million case, I guarantee you they would be willing to split it, but if your claim is weak or for less than $5 million, then the average US or UK firm will not want to share it.

Asking a third lawyer in the same field is one strategy. They might have an opinion.

In general, the quality of legal service you get really depends on how hard the lawyer works. You are much better off having a bad lawyer that works his butt off on your case, than a good lawyer that does nothing. Most lawyers just phone it in and do as little as they can to get a fee.

If it were me, I would try to have additional meetings with the candidates. The more time they give you in the meetings, the more likely they are to do a good job on your case.

Comment: Thanks, but they told me that all the fee is free. It's like a "group-case" (that many people lost money in that stock). Is there any way I can check how well those law firms are? (For instance, is there an industrial ranking?)